# Finding the equivalent definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

$\int x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1} dx $ (x=0 to x=1 )

I came across this question.Option A I could prove correct .But is any of the other three options correct? What should be the approach ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the substitution   $t=\frac{x}{1-x}$.